# The use of "of as"

Tags: grammar

A friend of mine asked me this question few days ago:

> What acts do you think of as a form of bullying?

If this is in fact grammatically correct, could the *of as* be replaced with a form of the verb *to be*?

> What acts do you think are a form of bullying?

The use of "of as" is actually new to me. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: _Of as_ is not a unit, just two prepositions that happen to end up next to each other. It’s a question form of “I think _of_ these acts _as_ a form of bullying”. Your alternative version is fine, too, but syntactically different, using a dependent clause.

Comment: "*What acts do you think of as a form of bullying*?" works fine when spoken.  When the words are written it feels a bit awkward.  I would probably change my verb (think of (as)/consider (to be)).

Comment: [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/think-of-as) considers 'think of as' to be a transitive multi-word verb (though it uses different terminology). Note that 'What acts do you think of as being a form of bullying?' is an unreduced form, and is replaceable by  'What acts do you consider [to be] a form of bullying?'

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote:

> *Of as* is not a unit, just two prepositions that happen to end up next to each other. It’s a question form of “I think *of* these acts *as* a form of bullying”. Your alternative version is fine, too, but syntactically different, using a dependent clause.